# Add css class to elements generated by loop based on entry in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, ecmascript-6

I have a couple of objects for environments (`envList`) and teams (`teamsList`) like so:

```
const envList = {
    dev: "DEV",
    sit: "SIT",
    uat: "UAT",
    qa: "QA",
    prod: "PROD"
  };

  const teamsList = {
    a: "Team A",
    b: "Team B",
    c: "Team C",
    d: "Team D"
  };
```

I am looping over them to show them like (sort of) a table:

```
<div className="App">
      {Object.keys(teamsList).map((key, i) => (
        <div className="team" key={i}>
          <span className="teamname">{teamsList[key]}</span>
          {Object.keys(envList).map((key, i) => (
            <span className="env-th-cell" key={key}>
              {envList[key]}
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
</div>
```

Note: The above is JSX, but it is not really a React problem. Just nesting maps over teams and environments.

Generating an output such as

```
Team A DEV SIT UAT QA PROD
Team B DEV SIT UAT QA PROD
Team C DEV SIT UAT QA PROD
Team D DEV SIT UAT QA PROD
```

I need to add a CSS class (`.red`) to highlight the env for any team based on the following `redTeams` array:

```
const redTeams = [
    {
      envIndex: 0,
      team: "Team A"
    },
    {
      envIndex: 0,
      team: "Team B"
    },
    {
      envIndex: 4,
      team: "Team B"
    }
    {
      envIndex: 3,
      team: "Team C"
    },
    {
      envIndex: 4,
      team: "Team C"
    }
];
```

if a `team` and an `envIndex` is present in `redTeams`, I want to add a class on the span for that environment. *There could be more than one entries for a team in redTeams.*

```
Team A DEV(red) SIT UAT QA      PROD
Team B DEV(red) SIT UAT QA      PROD (red)
Team C DEV      SIT UAT QA(red) PROD
Team D DEV      SIT UAT QA      PROD(red)
```

The above output is for representation, there is no (red), but a class added to the `span`

Here is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pwjxy82j5x?fontsize=14

Some advice on the approach would be helpful and appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to conditionally add className while rendering. Before that you need to create a map for envIndex to env mapping

```
<div className="App">
  {Object.keys(teamsList).map((key, i) => {
    const teams = redTeams.filter(team => teamsList[key] === team.team);
    return (
      <div className="team" key={i}>
        <span className="teamname">{teamsList[key]}</span>
        {Object.keys(envList).map((key, i) => {
          let className = "env-th-cell";
          if (
            teams &&
            teams.findIndex(
              t => envList[key] === indexToEnvMap[t.envIndex]
            ) > -1
          ) {
            className += " red";
          }
          return (
            <span className={className} key={key}>
              {envList[key]}
            </span>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

[**Working demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwl367ov5q)

Comment: Yes that works... Almost!

Except if there are two entries for a particular team in `redTeams` array. E.g `Team B` has entries for both `envIndex` 0 and 4, such as

```
const redTeams = [
    {
      envIndex: 0,
      team: "Team A"
    },
    {
      envIndex: 0,
      team: "Team B"
    },
    {
      envIndex: 4,
      team: "Team B"
    },
    {
      envIndex: 3,
      team: "Team C"
    },
    {
      envIndex: 4,
      team: "Team D"
    }
  ];
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/4r7wqk96x this doesn't add the class to the env 4 (PROD) for Team B

Comment: @Smarajit Updater my answer by using `filter` instead of find.

Comment: Didn't get your question, please check the demo link.